# Ordering a pagination by a relationship (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.3

In my app I have posts. I wish to show all the posts on the homepage, but order them higher if the post's user has uploaded an image. I can determine if the post's user has uploaded an image by checking if the user has a relationship with a row in the images table, like this:

```
$post->user->image
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
$posts = Post::where('subject_id', '=', $subject->id)
        ->approved()
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(18);
```

Currently, I am simply ordering it by created at, but ideally all posts whose related user has an image will come first, then the rest. I've been looking for a way to do this efficiently and in a way that doesn't just work on the first page.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::where('subject_id', '=', $subject->id)
        ->approved()
        ->select(['*', DB::raw('(SELECT count(images.id) FROM images INNER JOIN users ON users.image_id = images.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id) as count_images'])
        ->orderBy('count_images', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(18);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$posts = Post::where('subject_id', '=', $subject->id)
         ->approved()
         ->with('user')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'post.user_id')
         ->select(['post.*', 'users.avatar'])
         ->orderBy('image', 'desc')
         ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') // ->latest() can be used for readability
         ->paginate(18);
```

This code eager loads users to reduce number of DB queries and doesn't use raw queries which should be avoided, because mistake can make your application vulnerable to SQL injection.

**Explanation:**

We eager load relationship using ->with('user') method, then join users table, select all fields from posts table and only image field from users table, then order results by image and paginate results.

Result should look like this:

***App\Post:***

- id
- title
- ...
- image(from users table)
- ***App\User*** (eager loaded relationship)

  - id
  - name
  - email
  - ...
  - image
  - created_at

Comment: Will this not just order all posts by created at, and eager load all related users by image?

Comment: @DanielPahor This will order posts by user avatar and post creation date and eager load user. I added explanation to my reply.